# Any way to install ifort without installing visual studio previously in Windows?

Tags: visual-studio, intel-fortran

I was drawn crazy this several days to make ifort work in my windows Os. Everytime I installed `Ms visual studio` firstly and then installed ifort as suggested, I could not find ifort when I was trying to build in the visual studio. What's more, if I ignore the visual studio and solely install ifort, the complier will complain during compiling compland throw me error message like

```
could not find 'link'
```

I do numerous searching for the solution but none works. Some suggest I can adjust the parallel studio setting, but I didn't find parallel in the ifort folder.

intel visual fortran demand windows development environment
[image]
Could not find link when solely install ifort
[image]

Comment: Have you contacted the Intel Support? You are paying for that!

Answer (score 0):

You're using a VERY old version. But this version does include a Visual Studio environment. If you have a commercial or academic license, go back to the Intel Registration Center and download the installer that says "Includes Microsoft Visual Studio Shell" (doesn't have _novsshell, _ia32 or _intel64 in the filename).

It would be better, of course, if you were to use a more current version.